# After installing wine i can boot my pc only through recovery mode, but grub menu won't appear, only the bash-like line editing error

Tags: boot, grub2, wine

Hope someone can help me, i am kind of desperate. I've seen similar problems to mine here, but all the solutions required to boot through recovery mood. I did that once, but when i turned it off, the next time i tried to boot it through the recovery mode, the grub menu didnt appear. Instead i see this screen that says bash-like line editing....
The solutions to the grub menu error require to boot through the normal mode so i am stuck in this double problem. I can't boot it normally so i need the recovery mode, but i cant enter the recovery mode.
I guess i'll have to take my pc somewhere to be repaired with a usb drive or sth like that, but there aren't many places that work with linux in my town.
Hope someone can give me a hand.

Comment: Installing wine does not and can not be the cause of what you reported. What else did you do? And have you checked the boot order in UEFI ("BIOS")?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what has caused this problem. however, probably updating grub may fix.

boot your system using the command line page. with your system booted, first run these:

```bsh
 sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

in which `sdX` is your boot partition or device.

then run this command:

```bsh
sudo update-grub
```

then restart your system. the boot menu should appear if there is no other problem with wine.

hope this fixes your issue.